# How to remove the top entry (pop) from the emacs kill-ring?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I need to replace the top killed string to another one. I can (yank) it and then (kill-region ...), but after that, there will be two strings: the old one, and my new.
How to remove the old entry completely from the kill-ring?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be as simple as

```
(pop kill-ring)
```

Comment: That's very simple, thanks. But I'm not sure it is a good style.

Comment: This seems not to work very well, because it leaves `kill-ring-yank-pointer`. If the reason you want to delete the last entry is because it was e.g. a password and you don't want it hanging around in some variable, then @scottfrazer's answer (or the `browse-kill-ring` package from MELPA) is better.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why you think Oleg's answer is 'not a good style', but here is another way:

```
(when kill-ring
  (setq kill-ring (cdr kill-ring)))
```

You might also want to adjust `kill-ring-yank-pointer`:

```
(when kill-ring-yank-pointer
  (setq kill-ring-yank-pointer kill-ring))
```

Comment: I meant, that Oleg's way is too low level, but the yours, certainly, outdid it.

Answer (score 1):

`M-y` or `(browse-kill-ring)` to get into kill-ring-mode and then press 'h' for help. One of the entries is:

```
d               browse-kill-ring-delete
```

so just press 'd' with cursor over the entry to remove.